# What are the querystring parameters Facebook appends to shared URLs?

Tags: facebook, url, hyperlink, share

What is the `h=(some code)` and/or `ref=(some code)` at the end of the URL in the link of something shared on Facebook?

ie. If you click on an item that was shared by someone on their wall, the URL it takes you to has this code at the end of it. What specifically is that identifying?

Answer (score 0):

Ref is likely a tracking reference number so facebook can track which exact link you pressed on which page.
The h I don't know.

Try looking in Facebook's Developer help section.

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking the same thing. If there is anyone out there that knows what the h= is for I would appreciate it.